# How skip php script in bash

Tags: bash, while-loop, skip

I have a script test.php.
If it works correctly, its execution time is 5 seconds.
If not correct, it will freeze.

How can I control it - I want skip it if it executes more then 10 seconds.

```
 #!/bin/bash

while true do
now=$(date +"%T")
echo "Current time : $now";
  php-cgi /home/dev/test/test.php
echo 'Waiting 120 seconds';
sleep 120;
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `timeout`:

```
timeout 10s php-cgi /home/dev/test/test.php
```